# How do you download and launch iReport from maven/gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, jasper-reports, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

**This question is not about how to run executables from maven, how to use maven, how to download/install iReport, etc.**

How do you download and run **iReport** or possibly **Jaspersoft Studio** using a Java build tool like maven or gradle?

My understanding from the docs is not only that it is NOT possible, you also must run iReport on windows. This is because of the native installer:

> At the time of writing we are planning an OS X distribution to support Macintosh systems; it may be available in the future.

There is also no documentation I can find about downloading a jar and executing it, as you can do for stand alone Java apps.
For example:
https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534361/creating-java-launcher-ireport-372

To be more specific, this is what "running from maven" means:

1. Download the jars as a dependency/plugin specified in the pom.xml
2. Have a maven command that launches 
   the studio (in addition to the existing maven commands that launch the app). This must be a java launch, not some OS specific executable.
3. Dependency must be build-time and not compile or runtime, since launching a studio does not mean including the studio binaries in your app.
4. Typically, this is implemented as a maven plugin, none of which exists for iReport.
5. Java app launch has no platform dependencies.

This is what "running from maven" is not:

1. Downloading and installing the iReport studio yourself
2. Calling an OS specific executable, from maven, shell script or any other way
3. Having any OS specific dependency, other than what maven already has (practically none). This should work on mac and linux equally as well.
4. Performing any user action outside of maven commands
5. Having maven mimic human user behaviour. For example, mimicking a user downloading the studio and executing the installer (instead of the maven way of downloading it as a plugin/dependency).

Comment: it's unclear why you like to use maven to download and install iReport that is an IDE? What is the purpose? Why are you trying to use maven for this? I think you are either confused about the purpose of iReport (developing tool) or what the actual purpose of maven is

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the best of my understanding is that you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding something here, JasperReport represents Java libraries created to help you build reports. iReport is simply an interface that helps you visualize the elements in the libraries of JasperReport (Think of it as something similar to Window Builder in eclipse in case you've already worked with Swing or SWT and others in eclipse).

So to answer your question, can you use build tools like maven ? Yes you can use maven but only to get JasperReport libraries and use them in your code, nothing more.

In case you needed another visual tool but don't want to use iReport, there's a plugin in eclipse, you get an interface similar to iReport Designer.